# How to Sort List of Objects Based on a Property Value

Tags: sorting, grails, hibernate-criteria

I am using a CriteraBuilder to return a list of objects. I  want to sort this list (hopefully in the query) by a property value in the object if it equals status "PENDING". The statuses on the object can be "Valid, Expired, or Pending". The objects with status "Pending" I want to place first in the returned list. Note I want to be able to paginate this list.

**CRITERIA**

```
def getAllIds(Map opts = [:]) {
    def max = opts.max ?: 10
    def offset = opts.offset ?: 0

    def c = Identification.createCriteria()
    List<Identification> ids = c.list(max: max, offset: offset) {
        //sort here if status == "PENDING"
    }

    return ids
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'withCriteria' instead of 'createCrkteria'+'list' and use 'order' into it

See http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/withCriteria.html